# Align the text of a ListView to the right and the last line of text to left

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a ListView in which the text is aligned to the right, but I want the last line of text to be  left aligned, for better text formatting.
How can i achieve this?

Here is the layout file for setting the text to the right.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="right"/>
```

Comment: Align to the left, as in.. when it wraps, it is aligned with the line above?

Comment: Can you post a screen-shot with what you expect to have?

Comment: if i add multiline text the last line should be align to left.